# linker ignores /openmp in qtcreator on windows

Tags: c++, qt, openmp, linker-warning

when I try to compile the openmp cpp file from this  [website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw509c3b.aspx), I got a link warning saying that the openmp flag is ignored.

```
LNK4044:unrecognized option '/openmp'; ignored
```

I have already added these code to the pro. file

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS+= -openmp
QMAKE_LFLAGS +=  -openmp
```

or

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -fopenmp
LIBS += -fopenmp
```

as suggeted by some other stack overflow questions.But that does not solve the problem. 
Can any one help me to solve this problem? I am using the qt creator 3.1.2 with msvc2013 compiler on windows 7.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227595/does-qt-support-openmp

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815293/how-to-turn-on-openmp-when-using-qt-creator

Comment: I have already read those two posts, and I have tried all the flags or combination of those flags in the qt but still not be able to compile it correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSVC's linker does not need or accept the `/openmp` option.  You only need that option for GCC (in which case the option is `-fopenmp`). Although I use CMake now with QtCreator instead of qmake here is a sample from the last qmake file I use.

```
msvc {
  QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -openmp -arch:AVX -D "_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS"
  QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE *= -O2
}

gcc {
  QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -fopenmp -mavx -fabi-version=0 -ffast-math
  QMAKE_LFLAGS += -fopenmp
  QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE *= -O3
}
```

Comment: thank you, I think I overstated the question before, the openmp is actually running, there is only a warning of the linker. Now I solve the problem by taking your advice